# How could I apply an IF statement to all rows of a matrix (Matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am looking to apply an IF statement to a matrix like the following:

A =

```
 2     5     2     4     8
 2     5     0     0     0
 2     4     0     0     0
 6     8     0     0     0
 9     5     0     0     0
 4     7     0     0     0
 8     1     0     0     0
```

What I have so far is this:

```
if A(1,2)>A(1,4),
A(2,3)=A(1,4);
A(2,4)=(A(1,5))+1;
end


if A(1,2)<A(1,4),
A(2,4)=(A(1,4))-1;
A(2,4)=(A(1,4))-(A(2,3));
end
```

In the aforementioned code I am only comparing the 2nd and 4th column of the first row. 
Then the first row constructs the second row.

I am looking to then compare the second row and use that to construct the third row ... and so on ... throughout all 7 rows.

Could I add a 1:n to modify this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does not look like that to me. You calculate A(2,4) based on A(1,4). Then, A(3,4) will be computed based on the new value of A(2,4). You have a data dependence there.. And it seems you might have a mistake in the second if statement. You assign twice to the same A index.

Comment: Could the indices be incremented by 1 each time, in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the following loop

```
for i=1:size(A, 1)-1
    if A(i,2)>A(i,4),
        A(i+1,3)=A(i,4);
        A(i+1,4)=A(i,5)+1;
    end 
    if A(i,2)<A(i,4),
        A(i+1,4)=A(i,4)-1;
        % wrong index here? You assign twice to the same A entry.
        % the above line has no effect...
        A(i+1,4)=A(i,4)-A(i+1,3);
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Yes, I made a couple mistakes in the coding ... was trying to represent a larger matrix with the example. What I was having trouble with is the for statement and the indices. This clears things up.